# Which is the best way to display 'flash messages' in kohana v3?

Tags: php, kohana, message, kohana-3, kohana-3.0

I would like to know the best way to display *flash messages* in Kohana v3?

Some tutorials or examples would be helpful.

Comment: Retaged this question as it is not related with flash (as in adobe's flash tech), but with phh flash data (as in browser session data)

Comment: Flash messages definition:

Flash messages are messages displayed in response to user interaction with a site. Typically these are displayed as success or failure messages after performing an action which submits a form, or in response to an attempt to access a resource for which the user does not have permission.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you mean like Kohana 2.x's flash session variables?

[The latest Kohana supports `get_once()`](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.0%2Fdevelop/classes/kohana/session.php#L225) which is pretty similar to the old flash session variables.

```
$session = Session::instance();

$session->set('test', 'Hello, World!');

// The session variable is returned and removed.
$test = $session->get_once('test');
```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, the equivalent of $this->Session->setFlash() in cakephp. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the get_once is a great function, but what if you want to keep the data actually separate from the regular data, here's a basic class that overloads "Session" so that you can use "codeigniter" style flashdata calls with any data-store.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
abstract class Session extends Kohana_Session {

/**
 * This calls the parent Kohana_Session constructor and processes 
 * new flashdata to flashdata, and flashdata to old flashdata
 *
 * @param   array   configuration
 * @param   string  session id
 * @return  void
 * @uses    Kohana_Session::__construct
 */
public function __construct(array $config = NULL, $id = NULL)
{
    parent::__construct($config,$id);

    if(array_key_exists('___of',$this->_data)){
        //Remove old Flash data
        unset($this->_data['___of']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('___flash',$this->_data)){
        //Move current last requests flash data to old flash data
        $this->_data['___of'] = $this->_data['___flash'];
        unset($this->_data['___flash']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('___nf',$this->_data)){
        //Move Last Requests added data to the flash data
        $this->_data['___flash'] = $this->_data['___nf'];
        unset($this->_data['___nf']);
    }
}

/**
 * keeps a variable set in the sessions flashdata array.
 *
 *     $session->set_flashdata('foo', 'bar');
 *
 * @param   string   variable name
 * @param   ...
 * @return  $this
 */
public function keep_flashdata($k)
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    if(array_key_exists('___of',$this->_data)){
        foreach($args as $key){
            if(array_key_exists($key,$this->_data['___of'])){
                //So we were going to trash it...
                $this->set_flashdata($k,$this->_data['___of'][$key],true);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->_data['___nf'][$key] = $value;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set a variable in the sessions flashdata array.
 *
 *     $session->set_flashdata('foo', 'bar');
 *
 * @param   string   variable name
 * @param   mixed    value
 * @return  $this
 */
public function set_flashdata($key, $value, $current=false)
{
    if(!array_key_exists('___nf',$this->_data)){
        $this->_data['___nf'] = array();
    }

    $this->_data['___nf'][$key] = $value;

    if($current){
        if(!array_key_exists('___flash',$this->_data)){
            $this->_data['___flash'] = array();
        }
        $this->_data['flash'][$key] = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set a variable by reference in the sessions flashdata array.
 *
 *     $session->bind_flashdata('foo', $foo);
 *
 * @param   string  variable name
 * @param   mixed   referenced value
 * @return  $this
 */
public function bind_flashdata($key, & $value)
{
    if(!array_key_exists('___nf',$this->_data)){
        $this->_data['___nf'] = array();
    }

    $this->_data['___nf'][$key] =& $value;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Removes a variable in the session array.
 *
 *     $session->delete_flashdata('foo');
 *
 * @param   string  variable name
 * @param   ...
 * @return  $this
 */
public function delete_flashdata($key)
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    if(array_key_exists('___nf',$this->_data)){
        foreach ($args as $key)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($key,$this->_data['___nf'])){
                unset($this->_data['___nf'][$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get a variable from the sessions flashdata array.
 *
 *     $foo = $session->get_flashdata('foo');
 *
 * @param   string   variable name
 * @param   mixed    default value to return
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function get_flashdata($key, $default = NULL)
{
    if(array_key_exists('___flash',$this->_data) && array_key_exists($key,$this->_data['___flash'])){
        return $this->_data['___flash'][$key];
    } else if(array_key_exists('___nf',$this->_data) && array_key_exists($key,$this->_data['___nf'])){
        return $this->_data['___nf'][$key];
    }

    return $default;
}

/**
 * Get and delete a variable from the session array.
 *
 *     $bar = $session->get_once('bar');
 *
 * @param   string  variable name
 * @param   mixed   default value to return
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function get_flashdata_once($key, $default = NULL)
{
    $value = $this->get_flashdata($key, $default);

    if(array_key_exists($key, $this->_data['___flash'])){
        unset($this->_data['___flash'][$key]);
    }

    if(array_key_exists($key, $this->_data['___nf'])){
        unset($this->_data['___nf'][$key]);
    }

    return $value;
}
}
?>
```

I realize there was an answer to this, and like i stated before, the get_once method is great and all, but i enjoy auto garbage collection much more.

If you have any improvements on this code, let me know, its been great to me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this module, it might be what you are looking for https://github.com/daveWid/message

Answer (score 0):

I've written a really simple class for this once. Check it out below. Usage examples below

```
class Notice {
    private static $session;
    private static $initialized = false;

    // current notices
    private static $notices = array();

    function __construct() {
    }

    static function init() {
        self::$session = Session::instance();
        self::$notices['current'] = json_decode(self::$session->get_once('flash'));
        if(!is_array(self::$notices['current'])) self::$notices['current'] = array();
        self::$initialized = true;
    }

    static function add($notice, $key=null) {
        if(!self::$initialized) self::init();
        if(!is_null($key)) {
            self::$notices['new'][$key] = $notice;
        } else {
            self::$notices['new'][] = $notice;
        }
        self::$session->set('flash', json_encode(self::$notices['new']));
        return true;
    }

    static function get($item = null) {
        if(!self::$initialized) self::init();
        if($item == null) {
            return self::$notices['current'];
        }
        if(!array_key_exists($item, self::$notices['current']))
                return null;
        return self::$notices['current'][$item];
    }
}
```

Examples (provided this class is saved as `APPPATH . 'classes/notice.php'`):

```
Notice::add('Something great has happened!');
Notice::add('Exciting! I\'ve got something to tell you!', 'message');

echo Notice::get('message'); // "Exciting! I've got ..."
foreach(Notice::get() as $message) {
   echo $i++ . $message .'<br />';
}
```

EDIT: funny... for some reason this question popped up somewhere, didn't notice it was a really old one... sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://github.com/synapsestudios/kohana-notices in my project and I am very happy with it.